Question de pluriel
Certaines  préparations ont pour titre un nom au pluriel qualifié d'une façon ou d'une autre, comme ci-dessous.

moules marinières

crevettes curry-coco

fraises à la crème

Saint-jacques thaïes  en papillotes

ortolans à la provençale


En commandant, et en particulier lorsqu'il s'agit de portions, il arrive parfois que l'on utilise  l'article indéfini, et qu'on dise, par exemple, « Je voudrais un/une » suivi du nom ;  le personnel dans la restauration utilise la référence de l'article indéfini singulier couramment mais je ne me rappelle des règles selon lesquelles ils font ça.
Lorsqu'on doit écrire cela, faut-il utiliser le genre du nom pour l'article, et pour le nombre faut-il utiliser le pluriel ou le  singulier ?

« une/un moule marinière » ou « une/un moules marinières  » ?

« un ortolan à la provençale »/« un ortolans à la provençale » (« un » semble être ce que je me rappelle)


Je n'ai pas cherché en profondeur sur la Toile, mais les quelques essais que j'ai faits n'ont rien produit.

Ca dépend si tu as faim ou pas ;-)

@Frank Il va falloir jeter ce commentaire ;  votre esprit est sensé n'intéresser personne.

On entend peu ou pas l'utilisation d'un déterminant singulier pour des mets composés de plusieurs éléments (moules marinières, huîtres, coquilles St Jacques, crevettes, etc.), dans ce cas on dira plus "Je voudrais des/les moules marinières.". Par contre, lorsqu'il s'agit d'une préparation basée sur la transformation du produit (c'est-à-dire que le produit est travaillé de telle manière à ne plus être présenté sous son aspect naturel), on peut utiliser un déterminant singulier : "Je prendrai l'abricot en cinq textures.". On se réfère généralement à la pluralité ou à la singularité employée dans le menu présenté.
Pour les plus intéressés, je recommande la lecture de cet article québecois sur la rédaction des menus de restaurants.

« On entend peu ou pas l'utilisation d'un déterminant singulier pour des mets composés de plusieurs éléments  » : cela inclut, selon vous, le personnel hôtelier ?   On doit pouvoir reproduire leur paroles par écrit.

@LPH oui, j'y incluerait le personnel hôtelier. Jusqu'à présent, il ne me semble pas avoir relevé l'utilisation d'un déterminant singulier pour un plat "pluriel", si ce n'est, comme expliqué précédemment, dans le cas de préparations complexes ou de transformations radicales du produit. Par exemple, dans les grands gastronomiques (ou autres restaurants utilisant le même genre de formulation), on peut se voir proposé des noms du genre "La noix de St Jacques du chef" ou "La griotte confite" etc. où les produits sont multiples mais où l'on nomme surtout la préparation dudit produit.

Je pensais surtout à l'activité relative au service pendant laquelle les garçons  et les cuisiniers communicant les ordres  et les remplissant ont à énoncer des quantités ; ils me semble  qu'ils ne disent pas « une portion de fraises à la crème » ou « une portion d'ortolans à la provençale » ; il me semble que leur termes sont plus expéditifs.

Oui, c'est vrai. On peut entendre des choses comme Une marinière(s), une Saint-Jacques et deux Olérons pour la deux, trois frites pour la quatre. Pour ce qui est des ortolans, on ne risque plus d'entendre ça, leur vente étant interdite depuis une quinzaine d'années.

@LPH je comprends la tournure de la question (enfin !), alors oui je suis d'accord, il semblerait en effet qu'en cuisine, les commandes et ordres soient plus expéditifs et ainsi prononcés de cette manière (du moins c'est l'image que j'en ai et qui est souvent desservies dans les médias).
